# 燻る｛いぶる｝、燻る｛くすぶる｝、燻る｛くゆる｝ - difference?

Tags: pronunciation

Is there any semantic difference between the three? Which is used more often? Is there any nuance to picking one over another (formality, sounding more literary etc.)?

Comment: One thing for いぶる, I think "燻す(いぶす)" is often used, but いぶる is less common [citation needed].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Main Source: コトバンク

https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%87%BB%E3%82%8B-435662#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88

The example sentences are my own.

> 「いぶる」

This would be the simplest of the three in the sense that it only has one meaning.  It means "***to smolder without burning properly***".

「[暖炉]{だんろ}がいぶってしまって、うまく[燃]{も}えていない。」= "The fire place is just smoldering and not burning right."

This is one of the meanings of 「くすぶる」 as well.

> 「くゆる」

Main meaning: "***(for smoke) to rise gently***".  Once again, 「くすぶる」 can mean this as well.

「[線香]{せんこう}が[静]{しず}かにくゆる。」= "The incense burns silently."

Secondary meaning: "***to brood on (often in regret)***"  A highly literary usage.  You would not only sound weird if you used the word for this meaning in a casual conversation, but you will also not be even understood by regular folk as myself.

> 「くすぶる」

By far the most versatile and often-used of the three.

Besides the two meanings it has that I mentioned above, it also has the following meanings.

"To become sooty"

「[焼肉]{やきにく}で[天井]{てんじょう}がくすぶってしまった。」= "The (table-top) BBQ has made the ceiling sooty!"

"To smolder" (metaphorical)

「[農民]{のうみん}の[間]{あいだ}で[不満]{ふまん}がくすぶっている。」= "There exists smoldering discontent among the farmers."

"To rot away (in one's home or in a remote, non-urban place)"

「スミスはもう８[年]{ねん}も[家]{いえ}でくすぶっている。」- "Smith has been staying inside his home for 8 years already (answering language questions on internet!)."

"To remain in a lowly position"

「[田中]{たなか}はもう２０年も[係長]{かかりちょう}でくすぶっている。」= "Tanaka has been living the humdrum life of a lowly section chief for 20 years."

Comment: I actually forgot to click the "bounty" button　(more precisely, I thought it would be awarded automatically)...

Answer (score 0):

- <s>いぶる means to process something with smoke.</s>
- くすぶる means source of heat remains.
- くゆる means smoke runs.

Comment: As for the first one, aren't you mixing up [いぶる](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/14734/m0u/) and [いぶす](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/14709/m0u/)? (Or maybe some larger paper dictionary has such a definition?)

Comment: You're right, I do mix them.